# Spring Security exclude URL on custom filter

Tags: spring-security

```java
@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Autowired
   private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

   @Autowired
   private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

   @Autowired
   public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder
      authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
      authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
   }

   @Bean
   public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception {
      return new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter();
   }

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
      httpSecurity
         .csrf().disable()
         .exceptionHandling()
             .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
             .and()
         .sessionManagement()
             .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
             .and()
         .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/test").permitAll()
             .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
             .anyRequest().authenticated();

      httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
   }
}
```

I have a custom filter that runs before Spring Security. I want to be able to exclude some URLs (like `/test`) from the filter and Spring Security and others to be intercepted (like `/api/**`).

When using postman to test `localhost/test` it still goes through the filter even though I have `antMatchers("/test").permitAll()`.

How do I bypass the filter?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can disable the Spring Security filter chain for some URLs, see [`WebSecurity#ignoring`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/WebSecurity.html#ignoring--):

> Allows adding `RequestMatcher` instances that should that Spring Security should ignore. Web Security provided by Spring Security (including the `SecurityContext`) will not be available on `HttpServletRequest` that match. Typically the requests that are registered should be that of only static resources. For requests that are dynamic, consider mapping the request to allow all users instead.
>
> Example Usage:
>
> ```java
> webSecurityBuilder.ignoring()
> // ignore all URLs that start with /resources/ or /static/
>                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**");
> ```

Therefore, you can override [`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html#configure-org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity-):

> Override this method to configure `WebSecurity`. For example, if you wish to ignore certain requests.

To ignore path `/test` you have to add following method to your configuration:

```java
public void configure​(WebSecurity web)
    webSecurityBuilder
        .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/test");
}
```