# My authenticationTokenFilterBean is getting called on non protected endpoints

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt

**Context**: I am building an API using `spring`, and `spring security` to protect my `endpoints`.

**What I've tried**: I create a `WebSecurityConfig`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class WebSecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var unauthorizedHandler: JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint

    @Qualifier("jwtUserDetailsServiceImpl")
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var userDetailsService: UserDetailsService

    @Autowired
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun configureAuthentication(authenticationManagerBuilder: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService<UserDetailsService>(this.userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
    }

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun customAuthenticationManager(): AuthenticationManager {
        return authenticationManager()
    }

    @Bean
    fun passwordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder {
        return BCryptPasswordEncoder()
    }

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun authenticationTokenFilterBean(): JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter {
        return JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter()
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(httpSecurity: HttpSecurity) {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/user/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        "/",
                        "/*.html",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js"
                ).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
        httpSecurity.headers().cacheControl()
    }
}
```

**My problem:** My `authenticationTokenFilterBean` is getting called on endpoint started by api/user since I am doing `("/api/user/**").permitAll()` is this supposed to happen? Because this is calling my `JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter` (above) and my authToken is always `null` because I don't pass anything in the Authorization header(since this is an account creation and thats why I put the `permitAll` in this endpoint `("/api/user/**").permitAll()`

```
class JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter : OncePerRequestFilter() {

    @Qualifier("jwtUserDetailsServiceImpl")
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var userDetailsService: UserDetailsService

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var jwtTokenUtil: JwtTokenUtil

    @Throws(ServletException::class, IOException::class)
    override fun doFilterInternal(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, chain: FilterChain) {
        val authToken = request.getHeader("Authorization")
        val username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(authToken)

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication == null) {
            val userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username)
            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(authToken, userDetails)) {
                val authentication = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.authorities)
                authentication.details = WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
                logger.info("authenticated user $username, setting security context")
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = authentication
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response)
    }
}
```

**Objective:** Can someone help me discover if its normal that my authenticationTokenFilterBean is being called on non-protected API. And if it is explain how can I do it. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40475620/spring-security-exclude-url-on-custom-filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A request to an endpoint that's not protected will still go through **the entire filter chain**, which includes your filter. `permitAll()` means that the `FilterSecurityInterceptor` will allow an unauthenticated user to access the endpoint, but does not affect which filters the request goes through.

```
.antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll() //allow unauthenticated users
```

If you want your filter to only apply to certain requests, you can add a `RequestMatcher` that is initialized in your filter's constructor with a certain path to match. For example, `new NegatedRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/user/**"))` will match any path except your unprotected endpoint. Then in in `doFilterInternal()` you can do:

```
if(!requestMatcher.matches(request)) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    return;
}
// ... the rest of your logic
```

Now your filter will be triggered only when the request is not `"/api/user/**"` as desired.