# .requestMatchers permitAll() not working, how can I fix this?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

My application's `SecurityFilterChain` is configured to allow `POST` requests to specific paths. However, when I make these requests, it doesn't recognize the path and defers the request to my security filter for filtering, which shouldn't happen.

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
               .csrf().disable()
               .sessionManagement()
                   .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                   .and()
               .authorizeRequests()
                   .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll() 
                   .antMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                   .anyRequest().authenticated()
                   .and()
               .addFilterBefore(securityFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .build();
}
```

One of my controllers:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cadastrar")
public class CadastroController {

    @Autowired
    private CadastroService cadastroService;
    
    @PostMapping("/cadastro-usuario")
    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<Object> cadastrar(@RequestBody @Valid DadosCadastroUsuario dados ){
        try{
            cadastroService.cadastrarUsuario(dados);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).header("Location", "/login").build();
        } catch (Exception e){
           return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("/cadastro-loja")
    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<Object> cadastrar(@RequestBody @Valid DadosCadastroLoja dados) throws Exception {
        try{
            cadastroService.cadastrarLoja(dados);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).header("Location", "/login").build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The URL I'm using for my request is:

```
https://localhost:443/cadastrar/cadastro-usuario.
```

I've already checked the path I'm making the request to and the controller, but everything appears to be correct.

Comment: With Spring Security < 6 you could also completely disable security for these URLs, but this is now strongly discouraged. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40476128/5277820

Comment: A third way is to use multiple configurations, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75303651/5277820